# I can't use ds and execution_date updates in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to use a sensor for a directory with format YYYYMMDD, that's means every day the directory will change.

For example: Today, 20211129 sensor is checking if there are a directory with this name, if not created, that means the files haven't arrived. Tomorrow, suppose the files will arrive(and the directory 20211130 will be create) and the airflow have to be abble to change the date checking for 20211130.

I'm trying to do that with macros, but doesnt work properly.
Just for test effects, I set to every minute to see if time changed.

```
dir_main_name = f"archive/files"
templated_log_dir = f"{dir_main_name}/"+'{{(execution_date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%M")}}'
args = {
        'start_date': datetime(2021, 11, 29),
}


with DAG(dag_id='GCS_check', catchup=False, schedule_interval="*/1 * * * * *", default_args=args) as dag:

    sensor_check = GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor(
        task_id='gcs_polling',
        bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        object=f"{dir_main_name}/"+'{{ds}}'

    )

    sensor_check
```

I've tested with "ds" and "execution_date", but neither works.

As the log shows, the time of sensors checks differ than the time I put for the directory's name(just as example), the directory's name doesn't change:

```
[**2021-11-29, 16:48:52** UTC] {gcs.py:84} INFO - Sensor checks existence of : dev-datalake-archive-myralis-com, archive/files/**2021-11-29T16:48:47+00:00**
[**2021-11-29, 16:48:52** UTC] {credentials_provider.py:295} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[**2021-11-29, 16:49:52** UTC] {gcs.py:84} INFO - Sensor checks existence of : dev-datalake-archive-myralis-com, archive/files/**2021-11-29T16:48:47+00:00**
[**2021-11-29, 16:49:52** UTC] {credentials_provider.py:295} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[**2021-11-29, 16:50:53** UTC] {gcs.py:84} INFO - Sensor checks existence of : dev-datalake-archive-myralis-com, archive/files/**2021-11-29T16:48:47+00:00**
```

Stay in the same hour(2021-11-29T16:48:47+00:00)

Is there a way the value of directory be the same of the date(and hour) as time of sensors check?
like the last line, exec 2021-11-29, 16:50:53 and the directory should be 2021-11-29T16:50:53+00:00

Comment: 1. Your schedule is every _second_, not minute.  2. `ds` is execution date in YYYY-MM-DD format, if you want YYYYMMDD, use `ds_nodash`.  3. is this the log from the code above?  with `ds`, you won't get 16:48:47+00:00 part.

Comment: Hi, thats parameter that i've put in the interval is just example to reproduce tests. The problem is the variables doesn't update., the sensor execute but the ds and execution_date remains with same date that started.As a example, the sensor executed 16:50:53 and  the variable remains at 16:48:47.(last line of log)

Comment: 16:50:53 is the time of the log and `execution_date` is the dag's "logical date" (sort of scheduled time), so it usually won't match each other.  I don't know where "16:48:47" is coming from, though.  You have `{{ ds }}` in code and `ds` won't have the time.  

Are you manually executing?

Comment: Hi Emma, thanks for help! The problem was when I started the dag, Airflow has created 16 dag runs(limit in airflow.cfg) and I didn't see update, but what really happened was that not created more dag run. I've set time out and the previuos tags was set to failed and created new ones with the macros updated. That fix my problem!